# редирект htaccess с двойным правилом против дублей

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, редирект

Помогите пожалуйста с дублями!
нужен редирект `[R=301, L]`
?s&submit=Поиск = реальный адрес
?s&submit=Поискfffffyti = дубль

> ?s&submit=Поискlll = ошибка сервера
>   и примерно также с другими URL 
>   после слеша можно подставить символы и тогда либо 404, либо 500 ошибка.

```
domen-moy.ru/
domen-moy.ru/statya/
```

После слеша возможна подстановка строки поиска:

```
?s=чайник&submit=Поиск
```

Хочу чтобы ссылки состояли только из латинских букв нижнего регистра и знака `(-)`, т.е. `= [a-z-]`
Все символы и спец-символы после слеша редиректили на конечную ссылку.
Но тут может возникнуть строка поиска после слеша (её исключить чтобы не обрезало вместе со всеми символами)
А внутри строки поиска может возникнуть текст при поиске по сайту, и здесь также условие на латинские буквы, но уже без (-) , т.е. = [a-zA-Z]

для поиска и то не выходит:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\?s=([a-z]*)&submit=Поиск
RewriteRule ([^?]) /?s=$1&submit=Поиск [R=301,L]
```

сайт на wordpress  PS: неделю не могу решить задачу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Формулировка вашего вопроса не совсем ясна или даже совсем не ясна.

Comment: Крайне сомневаюсь, что в `%{QUERY_STRING}` встречается `Поиск`, скорее там нечто вроде `%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA`, хотя хз. Ни разу такое в голову не приходило

Answer (score 0):

> Хочу чтобы ссылки состояли только из латинских букв нижнего регистра и знака

1. Для адресов латиницей нужно установить плагин для транслитерации https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/cyr2lat/
2. В `s=чайник` "чайник" - поисковое слово. Тот текст, что ищет посетитель на сайте. Его просто НЕЛЬЗЯ траслитеровать и вообще как-то менять (вырезанием небезопасных строк занимается  сам ВП).
3. В `submit=Поиск` "Поиск" - название кнопки. Оно задаётся темой. В принципе его можно вообще не передавать.

Comment: ?s&submit=Поискiuuiiu

Comment: ?s&submit=Поискiuuiiu?;lkkl      это всё одна страница поиска

Comment: Естественно одна - пустой поисковый запрос. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: а реальная ссылка ?s&submit=Поиск   присмотритесь к тексту (найди отличия)

Comment: ?s&submit=Поискlll = ошибка сервера

Comment: Ошибка не воспроизводится на реальном сервере. ВП 4,7.1.

Comment: >?s&submit=Поискlll

Comment: Ошибка вероятно из-за твоих праивил в хтацессе или денвервера или темы/плагинов. submit и пр вообще ВП не учитывает .Только s

Comment: т.е. эти ошибки сервера = только ошибки недоработанного сервера -программы эмулятора?

Comment: эти правила лишь на половину работают, но работают...  плагины не хочу использовать, но реализовать как-то надо

Comment: плагинопаранойя? :) Это лечиться изучением матчасти. Ставь плагин, удаляй художества из хтацесса и будет тебе счастье :)

Comment: посоветовать какой плагин можно? а то чтитал про 2 плагина , но один из них устаревает вроде.

Comment: я ссылку на один давал: https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/cyr2lat/

Comment: Вообще устаревшие плагины ставить не стоит - могут быть дыры, Но этот безопасен - там простой код перекодирования кириллицы в латиницу. Да и автор обещал его вскоре обновить.

Comment: Попробую, позже тогда отпишусь.